# Alinear menú con texto e imágenes. Con CSS y HTML

Tags: html, css, web, responsive

Quiero centrar todo en el medio. Lo que quería originalmente es poner el texto ACLIF abajo de la imagen del logo. Y que el menú se extienda por toda la otra parte que quede. Pero que la imagen esté en la misma línea que el menú. Además me gustaría eliminar los espacios en blanco del costado y de arriba del `header`, pero he intentado con `margin:0;`, pero queda peor. Algo así:

[image: Preferencia de Menú]

Tengo esto en HTML

```
<header class="head-menu">
    <div class="encabezado logo-nav">
        <img src="Imágenes/Logo Estudio.png" style="float: left;" alt="Logo Estudio Aclif" height="106" width="166">
        <div class="txt-nav">
            <p class="logo">ACLIF</p>

            <nav class="menu" align="center">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Nuestra Empresa.html">Nuestra Empresa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Novedades.html">Novedades y Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Y esto en CSS:

```
.head-menu {
background: #000;
color: #fff;
height: 150px;
}

.head-menu a {
color: white;
}

.logo {
letter-spacing: 3px;
font-size: 40px;
color: #fff;
align-items: center;
}

.txt-nav {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}
nav a{
text-decoration:none;
color:inherit;
font-size:14px;
width: 80%;
} 
nav li{
display:inline-block;
width:10%;
padding:5px 10px;
background-color:#000;
border:1px solid #000;
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
}
nav li:hover{
background-color:#8B0000;
color:#fff;
}
```

Saludos!
Buen día!!

Comment: faltan varias clases CSS que no conocemos, por favor crea un [example]. Nota: ten cuidado con las tildes y los espacios en blanco dentro de los nombres de directorio y archivo que estás linkeando, te puede dar dolores de cabeza más adelante.

Comment: Listo. @JheymanMejia la pregunta fue editada. Eso es todo lo que tengo

Answer (score 1):

Yo usaria este html

```
<header class="head-menu">
    <div class="logo-nav">
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" alt="Logo Estudio Aclif" height="100" width="100"></div>
   <div class="logo">ACLIF</div>
      <div class="txt-nav">
            <nav align="center" style="">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Nuestra Empresa.html">Nuestra Empresa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Novedades.html">Novedades y Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Y para los CSS usaría flex

```
.head-menu{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 150px;
    width:100%
 }
.logo{
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    align-items: center;
   
}
.logo-nav{
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: baseline;

  }  
.txt-nav{
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.txt-nav ul{
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.txt-nav  a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none
    
}
```

Puedes  [ver como queda aquí](https://creatuweb.espaciolatino.com/sols/menu_nav.htm)

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! Saludos!!